# Side product obtained in reduction of cuprous oxide with carbon

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, metallurgy

So my book sates that in the extraction of cuprous oxide, the following reaction takes place.

$$\ce{Cu2O + C -> 2 Cu + CO}$$

This makes sense to me, if it is seen as the following two reactions coupled.

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{Cu2O &-> Cu + 1/2 O2} \\
\ce{C + 1/2 O2 &-> CO}
\end{align}
$$

But as per the [Boudouard reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boudouard_reaction), carbon monoxide is the dominant form of oxide of carbon *at higher temperatures*, however using *carbon for reduction is also possible at lower temperatures*, which can be seen from Ellingham diagram.

So, are both $\ce{CO}$ and $\ce{CO2}$ possible as side products depending on temperature at which the extraction of $\ce{Cu}$ is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ Paras Khosla. Your first equation is correct, but not your second one : $\ce{Cu_2O}$ reacts with $\ce{C}$ without getting decomposed previously into $\ce{Cu + O_2}$. $\ce{Cu_2O}$ is more stable than $\ce{CuO}$ above $1000$°C

Furthermore, $\ce{Cu_2O}$ does not react easily with Carbon in the solid state. The contact between the reacting solids is not good. The contact is better if $\ce{Cu_2O}$ is liquid. But $\ce{Cu_2O}$ melts at $1026$°C. So, the reaction starts at this temperature, forming $\ce{CO}$ which is more stable than $\ce{CO_2}$ at such a high temperature.